# Is it possible to do cross-organization Pull Request mentions?

Tags: azure-devops

I have some pull requests in some repo (called it Repo1), in some organization (let's call it A) in Azure Dev Ops. Is it possible to mention that pull request from a work item inside another organization (call it B)?

I tried looking into the organization configs, and reading ADO docs and found nothing.

Comment: As I know this is impossible, devops doesn't support this kind of cross-org actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to mention that pull request from a work item inside
>   another organization (call it B)?

As I know this is not-supported scenario. **Azure Devops** doesn't support this kind of cross-org actions.

In **B** organization we can't access and manage Pull Request in one repos from organization **A**'s project. So it's impossible to mention that pull request from a work item inside another organization.